# Probability of an event occurring

Tags: probability

> At a school in Utah there is a bench that can fit 2 people. We took an
>   exam and concluded that it is impossible to copy from someone that is
>   not sitting in the same bench as you. So, the teacher gave assigned
>   sits which were at random. The class consists of twenty students and
>   ten benches. We have that there are 12 A's and 8 B's. Now we have 8
>   A's sitting at the same bench and 4 B's sitting at the same bench.
>   What is the probability that this will occur?

I asked a question similar to this yesterday but my professor emailed me back today saying that question was impossible to do and he revised the question to this. How will I be able to do this?

**With the help of Mathguy and Andre I know that:**

I must numerate the seats so the first bench will sit 1 and 2, the second bench sits 3 and 4, third bench sits 5 and 6. (An analogy of this problem will be if I had 20 cards with the number 1 up to 20, where each number corresponds to a student. Thus I know that 12 cards has an A and 8 cards has a B). Then I must calculate that 8 A's are sitting at the same bench, then I must calculate/count the total number of ways to place these 20 different cards on 20 different benches. Then I must calculate the number of possibilities to place them so that I have 8 A's together and B's together.
Then, if I denote j to be the number of A's on even seats, where each bench has exactly one even seat. Then I can count the number of possibiites that lead to 8 A's together and then I will sum over the different possible j's.

Comment: Sounds like your teacher is making you compute to which benches he should assign you.

Comment: @Raskolnikov haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $20!$ permutations of people on seats.  To seat all the $B$'s together, you choose the four benches they sit on in ${10 \choose 4}=210$ ways, then can seat the $B$'s on them in $8!$ ways and can seat the $A$'s on the others in $12!$ ways.  $\frac {210(8!)(12!)}{20!}=
\frac7{4199}$